# Find set of vectors orthogonal to $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, orthogonality

$\mathbf{Question:}$ Find set of vectors orthogonal to $\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$\mathbf{My\ attempt:}$

The vector is in $R^3$ so we can let vector $\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
\end{bmatrix} $ represent orthogonal vectors.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
.
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
\end{bmatrix} 
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0
$$

$$
x_1 = -x_2 - x_3
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-x_2 - x_3 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
1 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}x_2
+
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
0 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}x_3
$$

Therefore, the vectors in subspace $W = span(\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
1 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
0 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix} )$ are orthogonal to vector $\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: $W$ is spanned by 2 vectors which are linearly independant, so its dimension cannot be 1.

Comment: Scalar product results *in a scalar*.  You have $\left\langle \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}\right\rangle = 1\cdot x_1+1\cdot x_2+1\cdot x_3$, a scalar, not a matrix or vector.  See [Inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) and [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).

Comment: Yes, edited my mistake.

Comment: As for the working you show... apart from the incorrect or inconsistent format of some of this you might have the right idea for much of it, but the dimension of a space is the number of basis vectors needed to describe the space.  You have **two** basis vectors, not one, so the dimension should have been **two**.  Those two basis vectors by the way should have been $\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$, not $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$.

Comment: So the span((-1, 1, 0), (-1, 0,1)) would adequately describe the dimensions of all the vectors that are orthogonal to (1, 1, 1)?

Comment: The span of those would adequately *define the space* of vectors that are orthogonal to $(1,1,1)$.  If we want to *describe* the space, we can do so with more words... specifically by stating aloud that there are two basis vectors in the span of what you write, and so we can state aloud that "*the dimension of the space is two*"

Comment: As for consistency in writing, if the problem statement were asked about row vectors, everything here should be written using row vectors.  If the problem statement were asked about column vectors, then everything should be written with column vectors.  You should not mix the two.  Those objects which are not vectors should not be written as vectors (*e.g. the result of the scalar product here should have resulted in the scalar zero, not the zero vector*).

Comment: Noted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space of vectors orthogonal to $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$ can be defined by $span(\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
1 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
0 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix} )$ where the dimension of the space is 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in with a non degenerate scalar product as this case the standard one you know that called $W$ a subspace of $V$ of dimension n, (in this case $W = $ span$(e_1+e_2+e_3)$ and $V = \mathbb{R}^3$) you have that

$$dim W + dim W^\perp = dim V$$

Hence if you know that you are looking for a two dimensional subspace orthogonal to  $e:= e_1+e_2+e_3$ all you have to do is to find $2$ linearly independant vectors orthogonal to $e$, which by dimension will span $W^\perp$. In this case you can tell at glance.